# UserBundle Symfony 2

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, fixtures

I tried to solve this problem myself but after three days, I give up and ask for help..

I receive "Bad credentials." erros (details: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ccgwpZtU))

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
      Common\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
      request_users:
        entity:
          class: CommonUserBundle:User
          property: username

        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        request_security:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path:  _check_path
                login_path:  login_page
                default_target_path: gemmi_start_homepage
            logout:
                path:   _logout
                target: signup_page

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

And my LoginController:

```
    <?php

namespace Common\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(Request $Request)
    {
        $Session = $this->get('session');

        if($Request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $loginError = $Request->attributes->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $loginError = $Session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        $userName = $Session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

        echo $loginError;

        return $this->render('CommonUserBundle::login.html.twig', array(
            'loginError' => $loginError,
            'userName' => $userName
        ));
    }   
}
```

Also my routing.yml:

```
    login_page:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: CommonUserBundle:Login:index }

signup_page:
    path:     /signup
    defaults: { _controller: CommonUserBundle:Login:signup }

_check_path:
    path: /login-check

_logout:
    path: /logout
```

And:

```
gemmi_start_homepage:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: GemmiStartBundle:Default:index }
```

And my form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('_check_path') }}" name="contactform" id="contactform">

                    <fieldset>

                        <label for="login" accesskey="E"></label>
                        <input name="_username" type="text" id="login" size="30" value="{{ userName }}" placeholder="{% trans %} nickname {% endtrans %}" />
                        <br> <br>
                        <label for="passwd" accesskey="E"></label>
                        <input name="_password" type="password" id="passwd" size="30" value="" placeholder="{% trans %} password {% endtrans %}" />
                        <br> <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-send" id="submit" value="Submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            {% trans %} log_in {% endtrans %}
                        </button>

                    </fieldset>

                </form>
```

User Entity: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wH47SCPg)

And the last one - UserFixtures: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1qXa47BK)

I know there is a lot to check but can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice you're missing a specific option, named `firewalls:` in your `security.yml` file? Or you accidentally left it out while you were pasting your code? The syntax should be like this:

```
providers:
    request_users:
        entity:
            class: CommonUserBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    # your firewalls definitions goes here.
```

I applied your configuration quickly, and I managed to pass the form. I was not authenticated fully though, but it did not throw me error for `Bad credentials`. Try editing your file (if that line is indeed missing) and see what happens. If that is not the case, we will continue investigating the problem further.

Comment: Unfortunately I miss "firewalls:" while pasting it here. So I do have it in my security.yml, so we need to find other issue. Thank You for helping!

Comment: There is a high chance that you indeed enter bad credentials. I pasted one of the passwords from my projects and I was redirected after form submission, just as expected.

Comment: Hmmm... For sure I enter correct credentiasl, I did It mamy Times. I think It will be another stupid,Simple issue.